# How to print difference between two files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have 1 file where data gets added every 10 min, I want to get updated data which can be stored in new file(inc1.txt) through script.

My path for file as /home/asda/Desktop/inc.txt

How this can be achive?

Comment: i don't know how to implement it in script but the idea is to take a snap shot name it as old and use diff command after 10 mins.

Comment: I think `tail -f updatedfile >> storedfile` you want right?

Comment: have you looked at the 1`diff` command? perhaps in combination with `tail` or just using `wc -l` and `tail`

Answer (score 2):

Use `tac` to cat the file backwards, and quit when you get to your marker:

```
tac /home/asda/Desktop/inc.txt | sed /Marker/q | tac
```

then add a new Marker at the end to remember where you last finished

```
echo "Marker" >> /home/asda/Desktop/inc.txt
```

This has the disadvantage that it alters your file, but you can grep out the markers when you use the file like this:

```
grep -v Marker /home/asda/Desktop/inc.txt
```

Of course, you should make the marker something that doesn't naturally occur in your file.